# What is the best way to Identify Google drive url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, content-type

I'm working on a project where I need to upload files to Google Drive. Files can be in any format such as Image, Document or Video.

I can see that google drive returns same URLs for all content types. For example:

URL for Document: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11bZBQ5dfsdferRER`

URL for Image: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11bZBQ5ererWEEWssdfd`

Upload part is done but I'm facing issue while showing files on webpage because I want to identify the content type of the URL to render differently for each files.

Possibly I can download the file from the URL and then get the content-type before rendering. But it's a last option for me because files may be larger in size and numbers.

Is there any easy solution around web so that I don't need to download each url to get only content type?

Comment: Can you get file names without downloading?

Comment: Yes, I've url's stored in my database.

Comment: Can you not just store the mime type with your URL in your database then for uploads?

Comment: @danielx yes, we can but what to do with the existing urls?

Comment: Use the Drive API to fetch the file metadata by extracting the ID from the URLs. This is of course given you have or can get OAuth2 authorization (access_token) for a user with permission to read (open) the files. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

Comment: @danielx I've users permission already. I'll think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible, as long as you have stored the files in a public folder.

you can then recognize the files based on the url, which would be something like this: googledrive.com/host/folderID/filename

Some more information on this can be found [here](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html).

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Actually all files will be stored in logged in users account. So, how can I get the host/folderId?

Comment: And even you were added *dead link blog*, did you checked it?

Comment: web hosting on google drive is deprecated https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drive API to get file metadata given you have the file ID and at least reader permission role for the file.

And you can extract the file ID from the URLs by taking the `id` query parameter.

See Drive API files get method: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get